# Grub2 commands to automatically boot from Windows (UEFI installation & BIOS firmware)

Tags: bios, uefi, grub2

The following chain of commands works when Windows is installed in UEFI and UEFI firmware is present. If Windows is installed in UEFI and that in combination with BIOS firmware the command will not work. How do I have to customize the command?

```
search --set=root --file /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
boot
```

After this command follows the error: Blue screen with "Your PC/Device needs to be repaired"
However, Windows boots normally if I do not want to boot Windows from the grub console using grub commands. So it must be the commands.

I have tried the following adjustment:

```
search --set=root --file /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
boot
```

then the error message "cannot load image" appears

Thank you for support!